# Scala case class copy method with Map parameter

Tags: scala

I became from a Java background and I am starting to learn Scala.

I created a class `Foo` which contains a Map[String,String] and an add method. This method simply adds elements to map and return an object of `Foo` so I can use chaining. I am trying to do this "the Scala way" so that, instead of adding an element to the Map and return the same object, I am trying to return a copy of the previous object with a new Map containing the new added element `(key -> value)`

```
case class Foo(map : Map[String, String]) {
  def add(key:String, value:String) : Foo = copy(map = map ++ Map(key -> value))
}

object Foo{
  def apply(): Foo = new Foo(Map.empty[String, String])
}
```

But when I try to add multiple elements to my Foo class, the map still empty.

```
scala> f.add("Oi", "Hello")
res1: Foo = Foo(Map(Oi -> Hello))

scala> f.add("Tchau", "Bye")
res2: Foo = Foo(Map(Tchau -> Bye))

scala> f.map
res3: Map[String,String] = Map()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: BTW, since you are adding just one entry, it would be better to just `this.copy(map = map + (key -> value))`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez it would be helpful if your comment explained *why* that was better.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez why is this preferrable?

Comment: @munk I realized _"better"_ was not the best expression to use, maybe _"you can also just"_ would have been better _(joke intended :p)_ - Because there are not strong reasons for that. IMHO, it seems better, because it clearly express the intention of just adding one new key-value pair. Also, it is like 3 characters shorter! Also, one can argue `++` is not optimized to handle entries with just one value, but that is probably negligible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not modifying `f` when you call `add`. Instead, you're creating a new instance of a Foo. The problem is you're not storing that anywhere. Try:

```
> val g = f.add("Oi", "Hello")
> val h = f.add("Tchau", "Bye")
> h.map
```

To clarify: you're not actually returning the same instance of `f` when you call `add`, but a *new* instance.

If you wanted to return the same instance, you would need something to be mutable.

```
// make the reference mutable
case class Foo(var map : Map[String, String]) {
  def add(key:String, value:String) : Foo = {
      map = map ++ Map(key -> value))
      this
  }
}
```

Or

```
// make the map mutable
case class Foo(map : scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String]) {
  def add(key:String, value:String) : Foo = {
      map.updated(key, value)
      this
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think `mutable.Map` consists of method `add`.  Maybe `+=` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Just to clarify, your Solution is the *Scala way*, which is to avoid *mutable State* whenever possible.

The only improvement is as stated by *Miguel* to add only an entry (`map + (key -> value)` and not a whole Map (`map ++ Map(key -> value)`):

```
case class Foo(map : Map[String, String]) {
  def add(key:String, value:String) : Foo = copy(map = map + (key -> value))
}

object Foo{
  def apply(): Foo = new Foo(Map.empty[String, String])
}
```

The beauty of having immutable values, there is no chance somebody will change your instance.

So for example:

```
  val f = Foo()                   // -> Foo(Map())
  val g = f.add("key1", "value1") // -> Foo(Map(key1 -> value1))
  val h = g.add("key2", "value2") // -> Foo(Map(key1 -> value1, key2 -> value2))

  f != g != h
```

The *Scala way* here is to use it *fluently*:

```
Foo()
  .add("key1", "value1")
  .add("key2", "value2")
  .add("key3", "value3")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the careful explanation